# How to pass multiple values in a instr?

Tags: vba

I have some challenges with this code. The code below works fine, but I would like to add another parameter it should check, so if the cell named "SkabelonNavn" is "auto 2", then it should also be defined as `IsAutoRater`.

I just tried to add it like this: `Auto 1; auto 2`, but it did not work.

Do you have a suggestion, so it will check both?

```vb
Public Function IsAutoRater(Optional ByRef wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    On Error Resume Next
    IsAutoRater = InStr(LCase(wb.Names("SkabelonNavn").RefersToRange.value), ("auto 1")) > 0

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        IsAutoRater = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Something like `IsAutoRater = InStr("ABC_Auto 2", "Auto 1") > 0 Or InStr("ABC_Auto 2", "Auto 2")>0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IsAutoRater = LCase(wb.Names("SkabelonNavn").RefersToRange.Value) Like "auto [12]"
```

Or use Regex to match multiple digits (if it goes above 9 etc)